# create dummy time series with same time stamp on several days (R)

Tags: r, time, seq

This should be fairly basic, but looking around and checking some functions, I did not seem to be able to get a solution.

I'm doing some time series forecasting, and facing the issue that I have irregular timestamps across different days. I want to create a dummy template with a fixed timestamp replicated on several consecutive days.

This does what I want, but only for 1 day.

```
dat <- data.table(
  DateTime=format(seq(as.POSIXct("2018-04-01 04:30"), by=("+15 min"), length.out=74), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
)

            DateTime
 1: 2018-04-01 04:30
 2: 2018-04-01 04:45
 3: 2018-04-01 05:00
 4: 2018-04-01 05:15
 5: 2018-04-01 05:30
 6: 2018-04-01 05:45
 7: 2018-04-01 06:00
 8: 2018-04-01 06:15
 9: 2018-04-01 06:30
10: 2018-04-01 06:45
11: 2018-04-01 07:00
12: 2018-04-01 07:15
13: 2018-04-01 07:30
14: 2018-04-01 07:45
15: 2018-04-01 08:00
16: 2018-04-01 08:15
17: 2018-04-01 08:30
18: 2018-04-01 08:45
19: 2018-04-01 09:00
20: 2018-04-01 09:15
21: 2018-04-01 09:30
22: 2018-04-01 09:45
23: 2018-04-01 10:00
24: 2018-04-01 10:15
25: 2018-04-01 10:30
26: 2018-04-01 10:45
27: 2018-04-01 11:00
28: 2018-04-01 11:15
29: 2018-04-01 11:30
30: 2018-04-01 11:45
31: 2018-04-01 12:00
32: 2018-04-01 12:15
33: 2018-04-01 12:30
34: 2018-04-01 12:45
35: 2018-04-01 13:00
36: 2018-04-01 13:15
37: 2018-04-01 13:30
38: 2018-04-01 13:45
39: 2018-04-01 14:00
40: 2018-04-01 14:15
41: 2018-04-01 14:30
42: 2018-04-01 14:45
43: 2018-04-01 15:00
44: 2018-04-01 15:15
45: 2018-04-01 15:30
46: 2018-04-01 15:45
47: 2018-04-01 16:00
48: 2018-04-01 16:15
49: 2018-04-01 16:30
50: 2018-04-01 16:45
51: 2018-04-01 17:00
52: 2018-04-01 17:15
53: 2018-04-01 17:30
54: 2018-04-01 17:45
55: 2018-04-01 18:00
56: 2018-04-01 18:15
57: 2018-04-01 18:30
58: 2018-04-01 18:45
59: 2018-04-01 19:00
60: 2018-04-01 19:15
61: 2018-04-01 19:30
62: 2018-04-01 19:45
63: 2018-04-01 20:00
64: 2018-04-01 20:15
65: 2018-04-01 20:30
66: 2018-04-01 20:45
67: 2018-04-01 21:00
68: 2018-04-01 21:15
69: 2018-04-01 21:30
70: 2018-04-01 21:45
71: 2018-04-01 22:00
72: 2018-04-01 22:15
73: 2018-04-01 22:30
74: 2018-04-01 22:45
```

I need to recreate the same pattern (starting hour: 04:30, ending hour: 22:45 by 15 minute intervals) on a time range of n days, let's say from '`2018-04-01`' to '`2018-05-01`'. Any easy way?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it all combined into a single column you could try something like the following:

```
dat <- data.table(DateTime = do.call("c",lapply(seq.Date(as.Date('2018-02-01'),as.Date('2018-05-31'), by = "day"), function(x) seq(as.POSIXct(paste(x,' 04:30')),as.POSIXct(paste(x,' 22:45')), by = '15 mins'))))
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why this does not work when we stretch the time window, for instance: dat <- data.table(DateTime = do.call("c",lapply(seq(as.POSIXct('2018-02-01'),as.POSIXct('2018-05-31'), by = 'day'), function(x) seq(as.POSIXct(paste(x,' 04:30')),as.POSIXct(paste(x,' 22:45')), by = '15 mins')))) doesn't seem to provide a correct output. Thanks

Comment: It has to do with the way POSIXct applies daylight savings time.  See my edited solution with seq.Date and as.Date instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below

```
library(lubridate)

lapply(seq(as.Date('2018-04-01'),as.Date('2018-05-01'),by="day"),function(x) { 
   seq(ymd_hm(paste(x,"04:30")),ymd_hm(paste(x,"22.45")),by="15 mins") });
```